# Macro for tables that take as arguments the column and row dimensions

Tags: tables, macros

I am working with tabulars formatted in a consistent way. Sometimes the tables are 3X3, 3X4, 4X4 etc nXm in general. As it is I have a macro for each of these tables: `\matrixIIIC`, `\matrixIIID` etc. Is there a way to define a single macro that would cover all these cases such that as syntax it would look like: `\matrix{3}{3}`, `\matrix{3}{4}` etc?

Below is a MWE that shows what I so far have for one of the macros. Ideally, the column and row numbering would also be automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\matrixIVD}{ O{RowName} O{ColumnName} }{%
\begin{tabular}{c|*{5}{c|}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}  &\multicolumn{4}{c}{#2} \\\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& & a&b&c&d\\\cline{2-6}
\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}} 
&1&&&&\\    
&2&&&&\\
&3&&&&\\    
&4&&&&\\\cline{2-6} 
\end{tabular}%
}%

\begin{document}

\matrixIVD

\end{document}
```

which produces as output

[image]

Oh, and the rowname needs to be automatically centered too!

Comment: The image is not produced by the posted code.

Comment: Aha, yes, you're right. I minimalised the code further. I'll repost a new pic.

Comment: In particular (with the original image) it wasn't clear if you wanted the content filled in automatically. I assume not now.

Comment: You are right. My idea was to have macro holders (imaginatively called like `\cellIA`) and these I would appropriately redfine befoe the call of `\matrix{}{}`.

Comment: Ok, perhaps it makes sense in context, it seems a lot more work to define 16 macros to fill in a 4x4 table than to simply place the 16 values in a tabular environment body?

Comment: Well, what goes in each cell is rather bulky (some of it won't even be displayed - I prefer certain parts of code to be clumped together - such as solutions to questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\zmatrix}{ O{RowName} O{ColumnName} mm}{%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\hspace{-20pt}#1}%
\kern7pt
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{#3}{c|}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{#3}{c}{#2} \\\cline{2-\numexpr#3+1\relax}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \mhead{1}{#3}\\\hline
\mrow{1}{#3}{#4}
\hline 
\end{tabular}%
}%

\makeatletter
\def\mhead#1#2{%
\ifnum#1>#2
\expandafter\@gobble
\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{&\@alph{#1}\mhead{\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}}}


\def\mrow#1#2#3{%
\ifnum#1>#3
\expandafter\@gobble
\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{\number#1\mbody{1}{#1}{#2}\\\mrow{\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}}}

\def\mbody#1#2#3{%
\ifnum#1>#3
\expandafter\@gobble
\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{&\csname cellX\@alph{#1}X\@alph{#2}\endcsname\mbody{\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}}}

\makeatother 
\begin{document}

\def\cellXaXb{a-b}

\def\cellXcXa{one}
\def\cellXcXb{two}
\def\cellXcXc{three}

\def\cellXdXe{the end}
\zmatrix{4}{5}

\end{document}
```